# Can I use variables defined in parameters.ini in validationor routing?

Tags: symfony

I was wondering if I could define some variables in parameters.ini and use them in various yml files like validation, routing, etc?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For any of Symfony2's YAML files that support `imports`, you can use the following syntax:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

Of course, this requires a bit of upgrading since `parameters.yml` is currently Symfony 2.1.x and 2.0.x still uses `parameters.ini`.

You would be better off passing variables around using service parameters. See [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html#service-parameters) of the documentation on the service container.

Comment: It's up to you to choose the format you want. yml FileLoader is supported since the beginning. It's the `symfony-standard` distribution that changed his default format.

Comment: @Florian: Half true, if you try to use the YamlLoader for `parameters.*`, you will get errors from the SensioGeneratorBundle as it relies on `parameters.ini`. An easy fix by upgrading that bundle which is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of validator and routing differs in its implementation.

DependencyInjection configuration files support the `imports` keyword.

Routing configuration files support the `resources` keyword.

Validator configuration files do **not** support import.

Translation configuration files do **not** support import.

Comment: So I guess I ca not do it. I have a regular expression that is repeated multiple times throughput routing, security and validation. It would be great if I could use one source so that I would not have to change it everywhere when change is due